# SignInManager IsSignedIn returns false in SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-identity

I deploy Asp.Net Core app with SignalR functionality (Gray.microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.server package) and whant to add Identity authorize checking in a Hub class.

```
public class FooHub : Hub 
{
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager;
    public FooHub(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager)
    {
        this.SignInManager = SignInManager;
    }
    //server method with authorization checking
    public void Method()
    {
        if (!IsAuthorize()) return;
    }

    private bool IsAuthorize()
    {
        return SignInManager.IsSignedIn((ClaimsPrincipal)Context.User);
    }
}
```

`SignInManager.IsSignedIn` returns false despite of my user is authorized with Identity scheme.

In source code of IsSignedIn method I found the code (simplified):

```
return principal.Identities.Any(i => i.AuthenticationType == IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
```

However there is `AuthenticationType == null` in Hub.Context.User (so, IsSignedIn returns false).

I know in Controller actions this field is mined from HttpContext instance. The question is how can I set it in Hub class manually to IsSignedIn  returns true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was because of `Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;`
I.e. in Startup class the Identity configuration should be

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => { 
    // other configs
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
});
```

So when client side requests a Hub method it is authenticated with Identity authomatically. `SignInManager.IsSignedIn` returns true if it is successfully